# php mysql insert sql sql injection

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-injection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

my code problem sory.

$yeri=no filtre;

```
mysql_query("Insert Into deney (vid,yazan,email,yorum,ip,tarih,durum,yeri) values ('$id', '$yazan', '$email', '$yorum', '$ip', Now(),'1','$yeri')");
```

How can I update data at the attack site to this inquiry?
How do I get this precaution. How do update the data in my table

Comment: You should look at [mysqli::real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) and also don't use `mysql_***` because its `depreciated`

Comment: How do they do it. What's going on here to write something like that.

Comment: @CialisCcialis I provided an answer, but I'm not sure I'm understanding what you are asking anymore. Is this a question about preventing SQL injection or learning how it's done?

Comment: I know now embed code, something which is mysql.

Comment: @CialisCcialis read http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php - the thing on the red tinted background. That's why everyone's suggesting you use something else instead, mysql_query and associated functions will be removed in future versions of php. I suggested an alternative, even gave you code to connect to your database using the new way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mysqli or PDO instead.

In pdo your code would look like - this is **SAFE**:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("Insert Into
    deney (vid,yazan,email,yorum,ip,tarih,durum,yeri)
    values (:id, :yazan, :email, :yorum, :ip, Now(), 1, :yeri)");
$query->execute(array(
    'id' => $id,
    'yazan' => $yazan,
    'email' => $email,
    'yorum' => $yorum,
    'ip' => $ip,
    'yeri' => $yeri
));
```

This way PDO does the escaping for you and it's safe against sql injection.

To create a mysql connection via PDO use:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
```

I usually add a 4-th parameter to that as well, since I like to write all my code in utf-8, 4th parameter is in my case `array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")`.

Just to clarify the following is **NOT SAFE - DO NOT USE**:

```
$pdo->prepare("Insert Into
        deney (vid,yazan,email,yorum,ip,tarih,durum,yeri)
        values ('$id', '$yazan', '$email', '$yorum', '$ip', Now(), 1, '$yeri')");
```

If you insist on using mysql_query, but that is **NOT RECOMMENDED**, you need to do it like this

```
mysql_query("Insert Into deney (vid,yazan,email,yorum,ip,tarih,durum,yeri) values ('"
    . mysql_real_escape_string($id) . "', '"
    . mysql_real_escape_string($yazan) . "', '"
    . mysql_real_escape_string($email) . "', '"
    . mysql_real_escape_string($yorum) . "', '"
    . mysql_real_escape_string($ip) . "', Now(),'1','"
    . mysql_real_escape_string($yeri) . "')");
```

Comment: How do they do all right, but what problem to solve. You need to know

Comment: This is injection safe => sql injection can not happen with this. I don't know if you asked something above?!?

Comment: How safe are they doing to me what this code but it is also required sample.
mysql_query("Insert Into yorum (vid,yazan,email,yorum,ip,tarih,durum,yeri) values ('$id', '$yazan', '$email', '$yorum', '$ip', Now(),'1',''); DROP TABLE madvideo;--')"); @xception

Comment: 100% safe, this replaces `'); DROP TABLE madvideo;--` with `\'); DROP TABLE madvideo;--` - the `\` tells mysql that the ' after it does not end the variable. As long as you use it the way I wrote it, with the bound variables and calling execute on it with an associated array.

Comment: mysql_query("Insert Into yorum (vid,yazan,email,yorum,ip,tarih,durum,yeri) values ('$id', '$yazan', '$email', '$yorum', '$ip', Now(),'1',''); DROP TABLE madvideo;--')");
no delete madvideo table error mysql. error logs.
you have  an error  in your sql syntax; check manuel  .....
'DROP TABLE madvideo;-- not working sql injec
@xception

Comment: @CialisCcialis updated answer again

Comment: plase help my turkish langues i don't speak eng :( soryyy

Comment: Benim cevap güncellendiğinde, başka bir göz atın bu anlamak türk çevirmek için Google Translate kullanmak http://translate.google.com/
READ - http://www.php.net/manual/tr/ref.pdo-mysql.php - in turkish

Comment: I just want to see how this deficit which the codes are doing it. Very kind of you, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape all input with [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) if you must use the old mysql extension or use the [mysqli extension's prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Note that the `mysql_` functions are deprecated and you should not be using them if possible (and it should be in your case).

Comment: How do they do all right, but what problem to solve. You need to know @jimp